# Path constructed from user controlled data in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

On SonarQube I am getting an error: `Change this code to not construct the path from user-controller data`
I am not sure how to fix this. The error is occurring on the first line of the function definition.

```
public static File genFile(String filename, List<String> header) {
    var mFile=new File(filename) // This is where the sonarQube raises issue
    .
    .
    .

}
```

It's a small project and the functions that I wrote only call this function.
Not sure how to resolve this.
The Controller calls this method indirectly. The Controller method is like

```
@GetMapping
    genData(String relVersion, String type) {
    
    String fileName= type +"-mt-files"+relVersion+".zip";
    }
```

It's probably because the fileName is constructed from the inputs that user provided.
Any ideas on how could I fix this?
**Things I tried:**

```
String fileName= type +"-mt-files"+relVersion+".zip";  
fileName=sanitize(fileName);

private String sanPath(String fileName){
return CharMatcher.anyOf(", ?\r\n\\/").removeFrom(filename);
}
```

But still the sonarQube error remains.

**Another Change:**
I added a method

```
validate(String relV){
// split the string and check that it's of the format
// 0.1.2 or 0.3 ...
// throw an exception otherwise

.
.
.

}
```

But still, sonarQube is giving this error. Which I think doesn't make sense as I am validating the String for a particular format.

**Finally, this worked:**
I added this check inside the controller:

```
if(relV.matches("\\d+.\\d+(.\\d+)?")
    throw new Exception
```

And sonarQube didn't throw an error now. Which is a little weird.  Because previously I added a function like validate(relV) and parsed it using String split and if the element can be converted to an Integer otherwise throw an exception. But SonarQube still gave an error.

Comment: Have you tried creating the File object in the controller and then calling the method genFile where you can do additional processing of the file?

So, the genFile will now take params of type, File and List<String>

Comment: Sonar suggests fixes for non-compliant code. What does it suggest for this error? Why does it not work?

Comment: @hermit I tried doing that, but still have the same error in Controller now. There was another function and I passed var f=new FileOutPutStream(fname), and called zipIt(f) The var declaration is in the controller.   and it gives error at that line

Comment: @hermit @Chaosfire  `if(relV.matches("\\d+.\\d+(.\\d+)?")
    throw new Exception  `  adding this code inside the controller worked